# Searching a list in a text file using Python

Tags: python, list, text-files

I have a program that registers an account and I am now working on a function to log said account in. I have saved the lists "usernames" and "passwords" to separate text files.

```
usernames = []
passwords = []
usernames.append(username)
passwords.append(password)

usernamesFile = open("usernames.txt","a")
for usernames in usernames:
    usernamesFile.write("%s\n" % usernames)
usernamesFile.close()

passwordsFile = open("passwords.txt", "a")
for passwords in passwords:
    passwordsFile.write("%s\n" % passwords)
passwordsFile.close()

while True:
    loginUsername = raw_input("Enter your username: ")
    usernamesFile = open("usernames.txt", "r")
    lines = usernamesFile.readlines() 
    if loginUsername in usernames:
        index = usernames.index(username)
        break
    else:
        print "Username not found"
        continue
```

My problem is, even though I have tested the text file and it has saved all of the usernames I have registered, the search still comes back "Username not found". I am not an expert in Python so if you could please explain in a simple way that would be great!

Comment: It doesn't look like your code ever does anything with `lines`, which I'm guessing is what you wanted to search through? (also: as a side note: even if you're just learning python, you should immediately purge the idea of ever storing a list of passwords in the clear).

Comment: How do I not store the list of passwords in the clear?

Answer (score 1):

You have not used `lines` read from `usernames.txt` file in your code for searching the username in it. So, modify your code as:

```
usernames = []
passwords = []
usernames.append(username)
passwords.append(password)

usernamesFile = open("usernames.txt","a")
for usernames in usernames:
    usernamesFile.write("%s\n" % usernames)
usernamesFile.close()

passwordsFile = open("passwords.txt", "a")
for passwords in passwords:
    passwordsFile.write("%s\n" % passwords)
passwordsFile.close()

while True:
    loginUsername = raw_input("Enter your username: ")
    usernamesFile = open("usernames.txt", "r")
    lines = usernamesFile.readlines() 
    if loginUsername in lines:
        index = lines.index(username)
        break
    else:
        print "Username not found"
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are writing this way

```
usernamesFile.write("%s\n" % usernames)
```

adding `"\n"` to the end of each username so your condition

```
if loginUsername in usernames:
```

is always `False` unless you remove the `"\n"` or you add it with `loginUsername`